# How to segue a tab bar control to target a different storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, uitabbar

I'm working on an app that previously isolated various UI pieces into separate storyboards. This was for organizational purposes because of the complexity of the app.  But now the navigation model is switching to a tab bar control.

The problem I've run into is that the target of each tab bar button needs to load a view controller (and all its corresponding views) from a separate storyboard.  The standard tab bar model (below) won't work for this scenario.

Is is possible to segue to a different storyboard's view controller when tapping a tab bar button?

[image: Tab Bar navigation]

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do this with Interface Builder. I believe you can load your view controllers in code and manually add them to the UITabBarController using `setViewControllers:animated:` or the `viewControllers` property

Answer (score 3):

You can keep your current setup with just the navigationControllers set to the TabBar and leave the other viewControllers inside their respective storyboards. You can then just instantiate the storyboard and set the navigation controllers view controller in the code.

Something like this:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"yourStoryboardName" bundle:nil];
YourViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"yourViewControllerIdentifier"];
UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController*) [YourTabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];//Or whatever tab index
navController.viewControllers = @[viewController];
```